# Spawning gameobjects relative to the position, width and length of another gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-engine, game-development

I'm currently developing a game in Unity using C# and I've run into a small problem.
I need to spawn a certain `gameobjects` relative to the `Spawnposition` and length of another game object. 
Now I figured that `bounds.size` would be the best function to use in this instance.
 As shown bellow I declare first  the variable that uses this in my start method:

```
public void Start()
{

 GameObject PointBar = (GameObject) Resources.Load("PointBar Horizontal");
 PointBarVectorLength = PointBar.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.size.x;
 PointBarVectorConv = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(new Vector2(PointBarVectorLength, 0f));

}
```

However, the `gameobjects` in question are inactive at start's call and thus I presume don't return any value for `bounds.size` when called.

Does anyone know how I can access the `bounds.size` or equivalent of an inactive `gameobject` or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you maybe draw what exactly you are trying to achieve? Why do you convert this into Viewport space?

Comment: Because my game needs to operate in a wide variety of screen configurations. Since it's a mobile game and so I convert world space to ViewportSpace

Answer (score 0):

As noted [in the documentation for the Collider.bounds property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html), bounds "will be an empty bounding box if the collider is disabled or the game object is inactive".  So your assumption was pretty much right.  Since the object doesn't exist in worldspace that makes sense.

I'm not sure about the most elegant solution for your use case but two options spring to mind.

1. Calculate the object's spawn dimensions by accessing its transform.localScale and factoring in the scale of prospective parent objects. That could get messy but you could probably also write a helper method to make it more manageable.
2. Instantiate the object somewhere off screen after you load it, access its Collider.bounds property to get the information you need then move it where ever you want it or store the information for later.

There may be better solutions but that's what leaps to mind for me.

Comment: Yes, the second option is what I taught of doing as well but I assumed that there was another method like Resources.load that could access object attributes when inactive that I might be able to use. If not I'll probably use the second method. The first looks like it will take too long to create

Comment: It can access all of the properties of an object loaded using Resources.Load() and its components but many of those properties aren't going to have useful values until the object is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using GetComponent().bounds.size.x;
instead of BoxCollider. This component can get accessed when the game object is not active.